# Firestore Phone Authentication Recovery

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

My future app as any other apps using firebase phone authentication may come across a situation where a user changed his phone number and/or his entire device, a new installation and a new authentication are taking place. 
Given that I am enforcing writes permissions to specific documents for that specific user, how can I model a recovery procedure so that one can access and write their documents even if he changed phone number and device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the user to also add an email via `user.updateEmail()` to the account after they create the phone number account. This can be used to help with recovery if they change their phone. You can then trigger the password recovery flow and then on successful recovery, re-link the new phone credential to the account.

Comment: I actually used similar solution by making each user have a recovery code the document auto generated id, tested for existance to validate user is the owner. I still comme across sime other anbiguities regarding firebase auth wich i am making a question about.